# SQL Server Merge Upsert only doing Updates and no inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, upsert

I want to record student movement when they swipe their cards on the door. Every time a card id and name is presented, I want to check if its a new combination which is not already in the students table. If not present then insert a new record with FirstEntry and LastEntry being the same date and cardid and name being the one that is sent in to the respective parameters. If combination already present then only update the [LastEntry] field. At the moment my query is only updating existing records, which means only the [LastEntry] field gets updated. For update this is normal. However, it doesn't insert a new record for a new entry. CardID and Name are the composite primary keys here on the table.

- I don't want to use the IF Exists(Select...) method for acheiving
  this.
- I want to use MERGE only.
- This action is to be done on the same table without using any temp tables
- After performing the action I want to see the affected records in either the update or insert scenarios. Only the following fields to be shown [cardid,  name, FirstEntry, LastEntry] and not the other fields in the table.
- The table has other columns which I don't want to show or return.

Here is my statement which only does updates

```
            MERGE INTO
            Students AS T
        USING 
            (SELECT cardid,  name, FirstEntry, LastEntry from Students where cardid = @id and name = @name) AS S
        ON
            (S.cardid = T.cardid
            AND
            S.name = T.name)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET LastEntry =  @DT
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (cardid,  name, FirstEntry, LastEntry) VALUES(@id, @name, @DT, @DT )
        OUTPUT $action, S.cardid,  S.name, S.FirstEntry, S.LastEntry;
```

Along with updates I want it to effect inserts as well for new records

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: your select does exactly what you told it to do. if the record with the key `@id, @name` is not there, it inserts that nothing.

Comment: Updated the question Nicky

Comment: @Aツ  how do I change it to meet my requirements? If it is not there then it should mean No Match, right? Then why is it not inserting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `using` clause shouldn't be querying the `Students` table. That's where you put the new values you want to insert or update.  It should look like this:

```
MERGE INTO
   Students AS T
USING 
   (SELECT @id as cardid, @name as name, @DT as FirstEntry, @DT as LastEntry) AS S
ON
   (S.cardid = T.cardid
   AND
   S.name = T.name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET LastEntry =  s.LastEntry
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (cardid,  name, FirstEntry, LastEntry) VALUES(s.cardid, s.name, s.FirstEntry, s.LastEntry )
OUTPUT $action, inserted.cardid,  inserted.name, inserted.FirstEntry, inserted.LastEntry;
```

**EDIT**

Your `output` clause should probably be using `inserted.<col_name>` instead of `S.<col_name>` for the returned column names to see the new inserted or updated values.  You can also use `deleted.<col_name>` if you want to see the value before it got updated (will be `null` for inserts).

Comment: Shouldn't I be getting the old last entry here, not just the values that I am sending in?. I thought that in case of an update I will be able to get the older values before the update happened as well. Is this doable?

Comment: You decide what you want to see.  You can use `deleted.<col_name>` to see the old value (will be `null` for an `insert` of course), and you can use `inserted.<col_name>` to see the new value, or a combination of both (make sure to alias your columns if you combine both to avoid ambiguous column names on output)